# How do I access an JSON array with boost::property_tree？

Tags: json, boost

```
{
    "menu": 
    {
        "foo": true,
        "bar": "true",
        "value": 102.3E+06,
        "popup": 
        [
            {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
            {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I get the value of onclick?

Comment: There are two things called `onclick`; which one of them do you mean to use?

Comment: This is your third question on Boost.PropertyTree today. It has pretty [decent documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/property_tree.html). Perhaps you should read it.

Comment: @Nicol - Somewhat ironically, the OP's example is actually from the Boost documentation! http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.json_parser

Comment: @wyz365889 - Did you read the Boost documentation on accessing data in a property tree? Heres the link - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/accessing.html

Comment: I had read it.But I can't find an  answer to  solve it.I hope you know  that can help me.

Answer (score 17):

Iterate through the children of the `menu.popup` node and extract the `onclick` values:

```
void print_onclick_values(const ptree& node)
{
    BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type& child,
                  node.get_child("menu.popup")) {
        std::cout
            << "onclick: "
            << child.second.get<std::string>("onclick")
            << "\n";
    }
}
```

The function prints:

```
onclick: CreateNewDoc()
onclick: OpenDoc()
```

N.B. Delete the trailing comma from the example:

```
{"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
```

---

You can't access specific children of the array using a single `get<string>(path)` or `get_child(path)` call. [The manual says](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/basic_ptree.html#id973373-bb):

> Depending on the path, the result at each level may not be completely determinate, i.e. if the same key appears multiple times, which child is chosen is not specified. This can lead to the path not being resolved even though there is a descendant with this path. Example:

```
a -> b -> c
  -> b
```

> The path "a.b.c" will succeed if the resolution of "b" chooses the first such node, but fail if it chooses the second.

The elements of the JSON array all have the empty string as name. You can access the `onclick` value an array element with

```
void print_arbitrary_onclick_value(const ptree& node)
{
    std::cout << node.get<std::string>("menu.popup..onclick") << "\n";
}
```

but you don't know for which element the access of `onclick` is attempted.

Comment: like this,we can get it.But I want to get it through the path of pt.get statement.

Comment: Yeah.Like this,I know I can't get it .But if I access an JSON array with jsoncpp,and I can get it through the path of json. So I think I can get it through the path of pt.get statement.But I don't know what to do. string s = "{\"age\" : 26,\"person\":[{\"id\":1,\"study\":[{\"language\":\"Chinese\"},{\"language1\":\"English\"}],\"name\":\"chen\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"zhang\"}],\"name\" : \"huchao\"}";
ptree pt;
stringstream stream(s);
read_json<ptree>( stream, pt);
string s2 = pt.get<string>("person."".study.[1].language");
cout << s2 << endl;

Comment: It's *impossible* to access the element using a single `get()`. Give up. Use the iterator interface (see my first example) to access the array elements.

Comment: If I want to modify it .What to do ?

Comment: Why in BOOST_FOREACH loop is used `node.get_child("menu.popup")` node ("child") and not "menu.popup" node itself? I don't understand conception, because when is called get_child method I'd expect some type like `list` which obvious can be iterated, but instead I get `ptree` object, why?